# how to extract data from an xml file using plutil?

Tags: xml, terminal

This is my file.xml

```
<key>FairPlayKeyData</key>
    <data>
    LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBD....S0tCg==
    </data>
```

I want the output to be: `LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBD....S0tCg==`

i try: `plutil -key FairPlayKeyData file.xml`

but output: `unrecognized option: -key`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-extract` option:

> -extract keypath fmt
> outputs the value at 'keypath' in the property list as a new plist of type 'fmt'
>
> fmt is one of: `xml1` `binary1` `json` `raw`
>
> an additional "`-expect type`" option can be provided to test that the value at the specified keypath is of the specified "type", which can be one of: `bool`, `integer`, `float`, `string`, `date`, `data`, `dictionary`, `array`

```
plutil -extract FairPlayKeyData raw file.xml
```

Comment: "xml1" it works, output content is:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<data>
LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBD....S0tCg==
</data>
</plist>

Comment: I had pulled that from the man page on my MacBook. You might want to check your man pages for your install, if you have a different version of plutil to find the appropriate format.